# How to ask someone "Are you going to/attending X?"; 'X' being a name of an event (a concert/someone's wedding/etc.)

Tags: translation

How to ask someone "Are you going to/attending X?"; 'X' being a name of an event (a concert/someone's wedding/etc.) My attempt:

> Coachellaわいくの?
> Are you going to Coachella?

Just wondering if there's a better way to ask this.

Comment: A possible answer.https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/3992/what-is-the-correct-way-to-say-where-are-you-going

Comment: looking at only the first paragraph of the answer on the link JACK put up, that would be one possible form, but if you look at the examples given, you'll see that with いく as the verb, there is one other, more common choice. I'd go with that one. へ can replace it in many situations, but not all, and いく usually utilizes the other particle. Sorry to be so roundabout.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the context, I'm assuming your question is asking someone if he or she is *intending* or *planning* to go the event we're calling "X." That being said, you have two ways to express this question:

- Xに行くつもりですか。[X ni iku tsumori desu ka.]
- Xに行く予定ですか。[X ni iku yotei desu ka.]

つもり /tsumori/ and 予定 /yotei/ both involve an intention or plan to do something, but there is a slight nuance between the two terms.

- つもり means that you have an intention to do something. You may or may not actually form a definite plan, but it's just that, an *intention*.
- 予定, on the other hand,indicates that you will go through with the intention (maybe you've made a plan that you will for sure be carrying out).

The short contrast is that つもり signifies intention, while 予定 signals a guaranteed or definite plan.

Note that, for either term, the plain form of the verb needs to be used.